# How do you power several devices of differing voltage and current from one battery?

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, circuit-analysis, batteries, circuit-design

I'm making a quadcopter with two little grabber arms. Here's the relevant hardware I currently have:

- 1500mAh 100c 14.8V (4s) lipo battery
- 2s-6s flight controller that's rated for 45A burst current (times 4 motors) = 180A max
- 5V OpenRB-150 servo controller that powers 6 small servos drawing maximum 10A (together)
- 11.1V power supply to 6 servos drawing maximum 10A (together)

From what I've gathered on forums is that I should connect a busbar to the battery and connect some DC/DC converter to the busbar to the different controllers/servos according to their voltage.

Wouldn't the busbar divide the voltage between the converters and/or cause noise or something? I'm an electricity novice and this is the first time I'm making a robot at this detailed level.

I've also read about PDB's, but they seem like overkill because I'd have to get a giant PDB that would provide 180A to the FC from one of the terminals when the the other controller and servos only need 10A each.

Comment: 1500 mAh? That's tiny for the load you're giving it.

Comment: And please, *please* don't try to get useful answers out of GPT. It is not a knowledge base, it is not giving you true statements, it's giving you things that *look* like an answer to what you ask because *that's what it's designed to do*. It is not, and is not intended to be, capable of answering questions correctly. I don't know why people are hyping it up as though it's some amazing solution to everything, but it's not.

Comment: At full power to all lift motors (180A,) your battery will last for less than half a minute.  At 100c, 180A is more than your battery is rated for (150A.)

Comment: What current do your lift motors really draw?

Comment: FYI this project is for a slow indoors service drone. Now that I'm thinking about it, I probably won't do 180A for the average flight - 180A is just the max rated draw from the motors. I'd probably stay at the continuous current rating of 140A. @JRE the 4 motors draw 35A (continuous current) each. And, I'm planning for the longer flights to be on average 4 minutes.

Comment: And thanks @Heath for the GPT comment! I almost did what it recommended but something told me I should ask here first haha so glad!

Comment: Four motors at 35A each is 140A.  Your 1.5Ah battery will last for less than one minute.  You'd need something like 9Ah for four minutes.

Comment: @JRE ah you're right. Thanks for the catch. I think I will go with a 9.5Ah 90C battery I found instead

Comment: Your flight controller can run on 3s, and your servos require 3s. A 3s battery and slightly lower voltage motors (likely not even necessary) would significantly simplify this design. If the 5V supply for the servo controller is just a control supply, there's probably a 5V <1A output on the flight controller that would be suitable.

Comment: I swear that within a couple of years there will be products out there, like power supplies or battery controllers, that will have safeguards built in against most commonly given incorrect advice from AI. The unintended consequence will be that AI won't get any better, because its bad advice will be hailed as "good" advice - "it works after all!". Yeah, it will "work" because the engineers have stupid-proofed the modules against customers who destroy them based on bad advice and then waste their time and money on support and returns.

Comment: It's almost to the point now where questions based on GPT "answers" should be banned outright, since they took no engineering analysis or reasoning other than looking for likely matches in the text corpus out there. It's a waste of everyone's time: person's who "asked" GPT, us who have to tell the questioner that all they read from GPT is wrong in one way or another, and so on. **Asking GPT is like asking well-read journalists for expert advice on technical topics**. They may be well read, but they are not engineers.

Comment: I agree that the battery is much too small for the high current man-carrying drone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a SMPS (Switch Mode Power Supply) (aka Buck converter) that will deliver 5 V at 10 A. Connect the input to your battery, the output to your 5 V servo controller.

Find a SMPS (or a linear regulator) that will deliver 11.1 V at 10 A. Connect the input to your battery, the output to your 11.1 V servo controller. The reason I allow also a linear regulator here is that the efficiency of some SMPS's is so poor, that with this small voltage step down, a linear might almost be as efficient. A SMPS should be more efficient, and will be smaller and lighter, than a linear, so is still preferrable.

Although your 100C battery is capable of delivering 150 A, that doesn't mean you should use it at that current. Using it at very high current reduces the capacity and lifetime significantly. If you have the payload available for a larger battery, it may be worth thinking about.

Comment: SMPS is the same thing as a buck converter right? I'm having a hard time finding DC input SMPS's (they seem to come in AC input current) but I'm finding lots of buck converters that seem to be doing the same thing. Also, I decided to go with a 90C 9500mAh battery - thanks

Comment: @Brian   Yes, I should have called it a buck

Answer (score 1):

> I should connect a busbar to the battery and connect some DC/DC converter to the busbar to the different controllers/servos according to their voltage. However, wouldn't the busbar divide the voltage between the converters and/or cause noise or something

A busbar is a thick copper bar used to distribute the supply voltage to several devices that require high currents and/or high current pulses while maintaining (not dividing) the voltage value. It is thick to reduce resistance and inductance.

The use of a busbar is appropriate in this case.

Comment: Makes sense - thank you. So I could probably connect the FC directly to the bushbar without any sort of converter, right?

Comment: The voltage must be correct for the FC. youor battery seems alittle light though.